# React Native Expo Dynamically Created Components Render in Web Browser but not on iPhone

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm creating a React Native controller app where buttons can be generated by the user.

There is a default template that is generated if the user wants to create a controller from a template.

When I go to view my app on my iPhone 10, the dynamically created buttons do not show.

However, when I open it in the web browser, the default layout is generated and everything is fine.

Not sure why this doesn't work on the phone, but I am using Expo to launch the app for my phone and the web browser.

(Note that the back button is not dynamically generated)

[image]

[image]

Comment: It will be better to share your code via snake. and then I can help you..:)